# New gradle plugin version (4.1.0): no longer returning any ressource fields

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

To get all drawables in an android app (using Kotlin) I call `R.drawable::class.java.fields`.
Since yesterday it worked perfectly fine but as I updated

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
```

to

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"
```

it just returns an empty array (so no fields / drawables are found).

---

I changed anything other than this and also tried to clean the project, rebuild it, invalidate android studio caches and to downgrade and upgrade again, but nothing worked for me.

---

Why is that and is there a way to fix that weird bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

I made it working by explicitly exluding the fields out of resource shrinking by adding an entry to the proguard rules as explained here: https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries/issues/331

You just have to add the following to the proguard-rules.pro file for your app module:

```
-keep class **.R$* {
    <fields>;
}
```

Comment: The latest releases of the AboutLibraries library will now include better proguard rules, which should make custom rules obsolete: https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries/releases/tag/v8.7.0